# How does watchOS find the main storyboard file?

Tags: watchkit, info.plist

I would like to have two storyboard files for feature flag reasons. Only one will be used at a time, but I want to have two files for switching back and forth between builds. However, I cannot find where watchOS determines which storyboard file to load.

iOS has a key `UIMainStoryboardFile` in Info.plist. But [watchOS has no such key](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/watchOSKeys.html).

When I check our current Watch Extension and Watch App targets in both the *General* and *Info* sections, I see no mention of storyboard files.

Note that watchOS **does** have `WKExtensionDelegateClassName` key for Info.plist, which will also serve my feature flag purpose. However, no code in my `WKExtensionDelegate` specifies a particular storyboard.

In Xcode, when I look at the current watch storyboard file in the *File Inspector* right pane, I see no special indicator marking for initial storyboard. Just in case it was listed there.

The [*App Programming Guide for watchOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html) does not explain how the connection is made either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

So after much experimenting:

## Conclusion:

- I cannot have mutually exclusive Storyboards in watchOS.
- watchOS seems to merge all storyboards into one thing.
- So when you reference a `WKInterface​Controller` by name, watchOS just picks the right storyboard.
- To feature flag storyboard scenes, just make sure you don't load the wrong one.

## Evidence

Building watchOS app extension fails with errors if more than one interface controller is designated "Is Initial Controller" across multiple storyboards. The error is:
`Multiple main entry points were specified. Please designate a single interface controller as the entry point of your watch application.`

I devised the following scenario and it worked:

- Main.storyboard with interface controller identifier "Bobby".
- Main2.storyboard with interface controller identifier "Sue".
- Main2.storyboard interface controller *Sue* "Is Initial Controller".
- Bobby has button which calls `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["Sue"], contexts: nil)`
- Button works as expected and loads *Sue* interface controller scene from *Bobby*.